# Google Chrome Bookmarks File is NOT in the Default Folder Everyone Says It's In -- So Where Is It?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-explorer, find, bookmarks

I have hundreds of bookmarks in Google Chrome, on my Windows 10 system, and they all work fine in Chrome, but I want to look at the place where they are on my computer, and I can't find them. I am trying to use File Explorer in Windows 10 to find the folder.  All the tech sites on the internet tell me to look at Username, App Data, Google, Chrome, etc. all the way down to "Default" and say that the Bookmarks folder is found there.  It isn't.  There is no "Bookmarks" folder under Default.  And yes, all my Hidden Files are visible.

One site said that I should look for a "Profile 2" folder, but that isn't there, either.

If if helps any, I used to use IE, and I imported all my IE Favorites to Chrome a few years ago, and so under my Bookmarks Bar the main folder is "Imported from IE", and all my subfolders for Bookmarks (Music, Geography, Politics, etc.) are under that.  That folder, however, is now much larger than when I imported it, since I've added hundreds of new bookmarks to it.  Anyhow, I can't find any Bookmarks folder anywhere on my computer, not even by searching for Bookmarks.bak.  And while I can find a "Favorites" folder, reflecting IE, there's nothing in it.

It's obvious that the Bookmarks are there, or I wouldn't be able to use them.  So they must be somewhere on the computer.  It's idiotic that I can't find them. Can someone give me some suggestions of little corners of File Explorer where I might find them?  Somewhere under Windows?  Under C?  Under Programs?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the `chrome://version/` address in the Chrome web browser.
2. Copy the profile path to the clipboard.

[image]

3. Open the profile folder using File Explorer.

You'll find a file named `Bookmarks` (without file extension). This is the file that stores all your bookmarks.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but you have given four numbers, but only 3 steps.  Did you mean "Open the Profile folder using File Explorer" to be Step 3, or did you leave out a step in between?

Comment: Also, assuming for the moment that you meant Step 4 to be numbered Step 3, I did what you said, and the profile path is: C:\Users\Acer User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default -- exactly what every single information page is telling me.  And to repeat, there is NO file named "Bookmarks" under "Default".  The first five folders, in order, are: Accounts, AutofillStrikeDatabase, blob_storage, BudgetDatabase, and Cache.  "Bookmarks" ought to appear between the two folders starting with "b" -- but there's no folder there.  So where is the Bookmarks folder?  Could it have another name?

Comment: @Richard: "Bookmarks" is a file, not a folder. This file doesn't have extension.

BTW, it's step 3. I've now edited the post.

Comment: Thanks.  No help site on the web explained that; they all said or intimated that Bookmarks was folder, some of them even showing a folder icon for it.  However, I did arrive at your answer eventually.  The difficulty is that I wanted to edit individual bookmarks from the File Explorer Window.  But you can't do that any more (as you used to be able to, when it was Favorites, in IE).  You could use the Rename function.  And there is no Rename function in the Chrome bookmark manager.  But there is an "Edit" function, and I figured out that one can change the title of a bookmark that way.